# Press and hold camera movement with mouse in new Input System?

Tags: unity, 2d, camera, input, events

I am transitioning to the new movement system and am having trouble figuring out how to move the camera when a mouse button is pressed and held.

Here's how I did it before:

```
private void Update()
{
    // Get the position of the mouse when a middle click occurs
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
    {
        _dragOrigin = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    // If the MMB is still held down, calculate the distance and move the camera
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
    {
        Vector3 difference = _dragOrigin - cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        cam.transform.position += difference;
    }
}
```

I have tried doing something similar in the new input system but it doesn't work:

```
public void OnMMB(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    if (context.phase != InputActionPhase.Started)
    {
        // Get the position of the mouse when a middle click occurs
        dragOrigin = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
    }
    else
    {
        // If the MMB is still held down, calculate the distance and move the camera
        Vector2 newPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
        Vector3 difference = dragOrigin - newPosition;
        cam.transform.position += difference;
    }
}
```

Here is how I set this up inside the Input editor:
[image]

The `Action Type` of the action is `Button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to detect middle mouse events and then check the mouse position.

In my current project I did it the other way around. I subscribed to the standard `Point` action of the pre-configured `UI` action map in order to catch mouse moves (or other pointy devices). Then I check the status of my own `MiddleClick` action within that event handler.

```
// mouse location on last update
private Vector2 lastPoint;

private void Awake() {
    // create instance of the class auto-generated from the InputActions asset
    inputActions = new MyInputActions();
    // subscribe to pointer move events
    inputActions.UI.Point.performed += OnPoint;
    // enable the bindings
    inputActions.Enable();
}

private void OnPoint(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx) {
    // obtain current mouse position from context
    Vector2 screenPoint = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    // convert it from screen to world coordinates
    Vector2 worldPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
    // check if middle mouse button is being held. 
    if (inputActions.UI.MiddleClick.ReadValue<float>() > 0) {
        // calculate difference between current and previous mouse location
        Vector2 delta = lastPoint - worldPoint;
        // use that difference to move your camera
        transform.Translate(delta);
        // adjust the worldPoint accordingly, because after the scroll it's now somewhere else
        worldPoint += delta;
    }
    // update lastPoint for the next frame
    lastPoint = worldPoint;
}
```